# mvvmcross setup class for iOS - mvxiossetup vs mvxtouchsetup

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

I am going through the example available for mvvmcross and I came across setup base class for the iOS.

-mvxiossetup
-mvxtouchsetup

Can someone explain what are the main differences and when you should use one more than another.

Thanks
Seb

Answer (score 1):

Since MvvmCross 4.0-beta8 the namespaces have been updated and cleaned. `Touch` was the previous name of iOS before Xamarin unified that to iOS.

So after MvvmCross 4.0-beta8 you always need to use `MvxIosSetup`.

You can read more about this in the blog post: http://mvvmcross.com/blog/mvvmcross-40-beta8

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me on this. Makes sense. That explains why a lot of the examples I find use `mvxtouchsetup`